# How to highlight skills relevant to a particular job to stand out

Tags: hiring

If you do very well in a course such as Reliability Engineering and other mathematics courses you take in your engineering major, but have no work experience related to the courses, how do you highlight this in a resume to get a job as a reliability engineer? Should you just list the courses relevant to the job along with the grades or ask the professors if they can provide references? Is there anything else you can do to stand out?

Comment: You mention the strong results in a cover letter, and you include your academic transcript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CV only include very basic information and exceptional results, for example, if you had an honour or highest grade in a related course, and it's not too many of them, you may include them very small alongside your academic experience (example: Degree of Computer Engineering, University of Foo Bar - Honourable grades in Reliability Engineering).

For the rest, you should include a cover letter explaining in detail which skills you learned in the course, where you excelled at and why did you get those grades.

Don't forget either to include your motivations for working as a reliability engineer.